# Wordpress CSS columns index

Tags: html, css, wordpress, multiple-columns

I looked for an answer but didn't found any...

I'm trying to make a 2 columns index for a wordpress (http://www.levinor.es/pruebas/). As you can see I have done it by adding divs in the loop that creates new columns. My problem is, as you also can see, that my sidebar runaway all way down to the footer and I don't know why... The sideshow have the right width for the sidebar to fit there, but when I expand the columns in a div directly in the wraper, the sidebar run away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to your stylesheet:

`.tribe-events-list-widget-events {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 30%;
}`

This will give you a 2 column lyout for your list.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I only need that my sidebar return to it's place.